# Can we add two columns when we are selecting them directly from a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I created a dataframe

```
'df1=spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter","|").load(file)'
```

Now I want to select columns from that dataframe

```
df1.select("col1","col2","col3")
```

This works fine. But can I concat two columns in the same statement. consider col1 as age,col2 as firstname and col3 as lastname. I am looking for output as mentioned below combined first and last name. I know it can be done using sparksql. I want to know this can be done in the above df1.select() statement.Thanks

```
col1  col2col3
23    JohnHarper
20    MarshallMathers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `concat` function as

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df1.select("col1",concat("col2","col3").alias("col2col3")).show(truncate=False)
```

or use `concat_ws` as

```
df1.select("col1",concat_ws("", "col2","col3").alias("col2col3")).show(truncate=False)
```

or you can use a `udf` function as

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

@udf(StringType())
def concatenating(x, y):
    return "".join([x,y])

df1.select("col1", concatenating(col("col2"),col("col3")).alias("col2col3")).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh Maharjan. I totally forgot to import the function. Its a silly mistake.Thanks

Comment: happy to hear that its helpful :) you can upvote both mine and madhu's answer too ;) its the up button

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
df1.select("col1",concat("col2","col3"))
```

Comment: Got an error concat is not defined. Do I need to import anything?

Comment: Can you post the snapshot of the error here

Comment: in pyspark you would need `from pyspark.sql.functions import *` or for specific `from pyspark.sql.functions import concat`